# Git Issues with a new project: ref with broken name refs/heads/main 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

Today, I created a new Rails 7.1.2 app and and a new remote Github repo called `gardening_by_zip` . After a few successful git commits and git pushes, I suddenly got errors and warnings when working in Git:

When I run: `git branch -a`  I get:

```
warning: ignoring ref with broken name refs/heads/main 2
```

Where is the "main 2" ref coming from?

When I run `git push origin main` I get:

````
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:[MYACCOUNTNAME]/gardening_by_zip.git'hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind hint: its remote counterpart. If you want to integrate the remote changes, hint: use 'git pull' before pushing again.hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.```
````

When I run `git pull` as it suggests, I get:

```
fatal: bad object refs/heads/main 2error: github.com:[MYACCOUNTNAME]/gardening_by_zip.git did not send all necessary objects
```

An article suggested removing the abnormal reference but that did not fix it.

Some of the errors seem to indicate that the remote is ahead of local but I'm the only developer working on this project. Any ideas what's going on?

A few months ago I could create apps and push to GitHub no problem. This was my 2nd attempt, as an exiting app I re-starting working on fell to the same errors. This time I created a new app in a new local directory and a new Github repo and this still happened!

Comment: Did you somehow modify the default branch name? What's the output of `git config --get-all init.defaultbranch`?

Comment: `refs/heads/main 2` is not a valid branch name due to the space. If `.git/refs/heads/main 2` exits, remove it.

Comment: The result of `git config --get-all init.defaultbranch` = `main`

Even after removing `main 2` did not seem to help

Answer (score 0):

FIXED! My issues were related to my desktop folder syncing with iCloud! [This post](https://architchandra.com/articles/a-side-effect-of-storing-a-git-repository-in-icloud-drive) helped.

At some point, I may have upgraded my OS or changed iCloud settings and it seems to have auto-converted my desktop “coding” folder to an iCloud-enabled folder. THis allowed git to work right away for a short time, but I assume after the iCloud folder ran it's next sync, it seemed to have been creating the "main 2" reference, leading to all the errors.

Today, when I disabled the “sync folders” setting (Preferences>iCloud Drive>Options and unchecked "Desktop and Documents Folders."), it removed the folder from local and the folder is now only in my icloud!?! What, those were all my coding projects!

To test, I created a new desktop folder (after iCloud disabled), created a new test project, and now Git & Github work like a charm!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xeS8.png)